# Year Month Day directory structure for FTP uploaded files with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp, directory

I currently have a PowerShell script for periodically uploading certain files to an FTP server. This script dumps every file into one main folder.
What I would like to have is a script that uploads the files in a (root)/year/month/day structure.

I have checked **a lot** of places for some script I would be able to use for this purpose, but couldn't get any of them to work.

Any suggestions? I must've tried the first 100 results on google.

'Dump it all into one folder' upload script:

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient  

$webclient.Credentials = New-Object
System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass)   

foreach($item in ($checkitems)){  

    Write-host  "Uploading $item..."  -ForegroundColor Green 
    $dt = Get-Date 
    Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Uploading $item..." 

    $name=$item.Name
    $name=[System.Uri]::EscapeDataString($name)
    $uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp+$name+"")
    $webclient.UploadFile($uri, $item.FullName) 

    if($error -ne $null) 
    { 
        Write-Host "Items will not be moved" -ForegroundColor Red 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Moving $item to processed" -ForegroundColor green 
        Move-Item $item.Fullname $processed 
        $dt = Get-Date 
        Add-Content $log3 "$dt : Moving $item to processed" 
    } 
 }
```

Some of the sources I already checked, for completeness sake:

- [Creating a directory on remote FTP using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739366/creating-a-directory-on-remote-ftp-using-powershell)
- https://superuser.com/questions/516232/creating-a-folder-named-after-the-current-date-and-time (can't get this to work with FTP?)
- [Powrshell script to move files into year/month folders based on creation timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103613/powrshell-script-to-move-files-into-year-month-folders-based-on-creation-timesta)
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/486290-help-with-powershell-script-ftp-upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will upload the file to `yy/mm/dd` folder:

```
$uri = New-Object System.Uri($ftp + $(Get-Date -f "yyyy/MM/dd") + "/" + $name)
```

*(assuming the `$ftp` already ends with a slash)*

But the folder has to exist already.

---

If the folder does not exist, you have to create it:
[Creating a directory on remote FTP using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5739366/850848)

You may need to create all the levels:

- `$ftp + $(Get-Date -f "yyyy")`
- `$ftp + $(Get-Date -f "yyyy/MM")`
- `$ftp + $(Get-Date -f "yyyy/MM/dd")`

---

Obviously storing the `Get-Date` to a variable and reusing it, is a good idea. To protect your from problems, if a new day started in the middle of the execution.

Comment: Would I need to add a check on every uploaded file to check if the directories already exist?
What would happen when the folder (with a file in it already) was 'created again' when another file recreated the folder? Would that throw an error?

Comment: Yes, it would throw an error. It's up to you, if you choose to check first and create only, if it does not exist. Or just try always and ignore errors.

Comment: I am getting errors about the uri value not being a String. I tried converting it to one like this:
 Edit: markup is hard. Link: https://i.imgur.com/f3Dx7md.png

Comment: I managed to fix it by placing brackets around it, `(Create-FtpDirectory $uri $user $pass)` instead of `Create-FtpDirectory $uri $user $pass`...

Onwards with my Powershell adventure!